# How to put text on picture that comes out of a database?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap and i have my picture in my rows and cols, but i can't find a way to put a text over this picture. Is there somehow a way to make this possible?

```
<div class="container-fluid">
@foreach (Item items in Model.Items)
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                <img src="~/images/@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => items.Picture)" />
        </div> 
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Set the image as a background of a `div` and put the text in that`div`.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but is that even possible when it comes out of a database? The picture is saved in the database and as far as i know you can't set that as a background image, if so, how should i do that?

Comment: @SeeSharp of course you can. It would be pointless to have a picture in a database if you can't use it. Just set the picture as the background picture of a div.

Comment: How would i do that in the little code i have right there with the foreach?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in css

```
.row {
 background-image: url("~/images/@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => items.Picture)");
}
```

Or something like this:

```
   <div class="container-fluid">
       @foreach (Item items in Model.Items)
     {
    <div class="row" style=background-image:url("~/images/@Html.DisplayFor (modelItem => items.Picture)">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                <img src="~/images/@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => items.Picture)" />
        </div> 
    </div>
     }
```

Comment: This isn't working. It doesn't show any pictures. This is probably because the css doesn't know anything about a model.

Comment: If you can show the image on a page, then you can use that as a css property.

Comment: I have it like this right now and it doesn't want to show the image.{<div class="container-fluid" id="caseTest">
    @foreach (Item items in Model.Items)
    {
        <div class="row" style="background-image:url('~/images/@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => items.Picture)');">
            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
               <div class="col-md-3">
                   @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => items.Name)
               </div>
            </div> 
        </div>
    } }

Comment: The pictures show on the page when i have it like i had in the beginning. The problem is as soon as it needs to be a background image it doesn't show anymore.

Comment: So when the page loads with this code,  what does the source look like on client side?

Comment: With the new code it doesn't show anything (i only have this little code on a file atm) with my own foreach it shows the pictures out of the database.

Comment: Do view source in the browser and see what is inside the div style.

Comment: It only shows a itemName that i added to it to check if it works. The image needs to be set to the background at a different way.

Comment: I don't know what twitter-bootstrap is, so not sure how the image is showing on the page. But your page is standard HTML then your for loop setting the scr proterty of the img tags. So you should be able to do the same with <div> background-image.

Comment: Can you edit and add some client side source to your question.